# Reference Request for TQFTs

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory, extended-tqft

I had originally asked this question on [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081736/tqfts-and-categories-references) but have not obtained any answers, so I decided to post this here. (I have flagged the MSE post to be moved to MathOverflow, for the administrators.)

This question is in similar spirit to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079779/methods-of-theoretical-physics-for-mathematicians/), but

> I'm asking for references that meet all or one of the following criteria:
>
> - a general formulation of the theory of TQFTs from the mathematics perspective that also explains the significance of the results in physics, and
> - pure mathematical applications of TQFTs defined using categories.
>
> I know about Urs Schreiber *et. al*'s and Lurie's paper, but are there others?

Note that by "TQFT" I mean ordinary TQFTs and/or extended TQFTs. Also, as I don't have university access, I'd appreciate it if the references were available online in some form.

Comment: A commented list of references with further pointers is here: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+quantum+field+theory#References

Comment: @Urs Thanks! I'd seen the mathematical references, but do you know of more physics resources?

Comment: Did you look at the original articles by Witten here http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+quantum+field+theory#OriginInPhysics ?

Comment: @Urs Not completely, no. I want to set a reading list first and then work my way through, so that I know what I'll be studying later.

Comment: I'd suggest Witten 91 http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+quantum+field+theory#Witten91 and Cordes-Moore-Ramgoolam 94 http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological%20quantum%20field%20theory#CordesMooreRamgoolam94

Comment: @Urs I'll read through them. Thanks for the references! (The latter is very long, it may take me some time to read through it! (-:)

Comment: @Urs Since you're here, could you tell some sources for learning supersymmetry mathematically (_without_ reference to physics)? I know that it's a strange request, but I think I'll be able to obtain a better intuition by studying it from a mathematical PoV.

Comment: For mathematical supersymmetry I recommend the articles by D. Freed listed here http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supersymmetry#ReferencesTextbooksAndLectures particularly the "Five lectures on supersymmetry" http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Five+lectures+on+supersymmetry and his article with Deligne http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/supersymmetry#DeligneFreed99

Comment: @Urs Thanks! I'll read them when I have the chance.